# Using chi-squared testing with a model known to be imperfect

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, optimization

I have an optimisation problem, in which I use a $\chi^2$ test statistic between model and data to define a goodness of fit. The numerical optimum of this is (with technical tricks) easily found, but I also want to derive statistically well-motivated variations from the best-fit configuration in order to e.g. cover 68% of statistical uncertainty.

The problem is that there are many, many observables in the fit, and no-one believes that the "truth" is to be found anywhere in the parameter space of our model. This is reflected in the minimum $\chi^2/k$ for $k$ degrees of freedom being significantly larger than 1.

I can't find any discussion of the "correct" approach to making a probabilistic interpretation of a $\chi^2$ test where the model probably does not contain the perfect answer. Are there any established tactics for handling this situation, or others in which the resulting distribution of optimised test statistics significantly deviates from a $\chi^2_k$? Preferably something that doesn't involve only restricting to the subset of observables that can be perfectly described: we need the others to not be terrible, too!

Comment: I wouldn't know how to calculate the optimum of a goodness-of-fit test. Please provide a reference, or a short description of how you did it (thanks in advance!). But, I am not quite sure what is it, you are asking: As no model is ever perfectly fitting the data (read error-less or 'true'), no model will have a perfect GoF. If these errors exceeds some predefined level (of a certain test), most often set at the regular significance level of 0.05 of the corresponding p-value, we consider the model 'miscalibrated' or 'a bad fit'. I am not sure this answers your question though...

Comment: @IWS Thanks -- sorry that my nomenclature is probably not quite correct! The optimisation is numerical: a MC minimisation routine with the chi2 as objective function. My question is about how to handle models where even with infinite statistics the data cannot be perfectly described by any point in the param space. The chi2 pdf is derived assuming (Gaussian) statistical errors only, so a model with systematic inability to describe the data even in principle will not have a chi2-distributed test statistic. How best to deal with this and construct some meaningful "p-value"ish contours?

Comment: I'm coming to the maybe obvious view that the "special usefulness" of chi2 tests only applies in the ideal situation where the model could in-principle be perfect and there are no systematic uncertainties, i.e. the deviations from perfect fit are purely statistical (and Gaussian). When not in this situation, it's less convenient but the pdf of the test statistic can hopefully be empirically obtained, and confidence limits numerically computed from it. The same could be done for a true chi2 test statistic, but it's obviously more convenient to use the analytic pdf and CLs. Hope this is correct!